# Trying to make an Array of image and pass the image to UIImageView

Tags: swift

I'm trying to put my images into `var picture` which I declare as  `[UIImage]`. But I kept finding error ... ?

I'm new to programming .

This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {



@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBAction func playButton(sender: AnyObject) {

}

@IBAction func stopButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    player.stop()

}
var player:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

var files = ["song1", "song2","song3","song4","song5","song6","song7"]

var name:String = ""

var picture:[UIImage] = [
    UIImage(named: "pic/1.jpg")!,
    UIImage(named: "pic/2.jpg")!,
    UIImage(named: "pic/3.jpg")!,
    UIImage(named: "pic/4.jpg")!,
    UIImage(named: "pic/5.jpg")!,
    UIImage(named: "pic/6.jpg")!,
    UIImage(named: "pic/7.jpg")!,
    UIImage(named: "pic/8.jpg")!,    ]


var condition:Bool = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



}

override func motionEnded(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {

    if event.subtype == UIEventSubtype.MotionShake {





        var randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(files.count)))


        var fileLocation = NSString(string:NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sounds/" + files[randomNumber], ofType: "mp3")!)


        var error:NSError? = nil
        player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: fileLocation), error: &error)

        player.play()

        var i = randomNumber

       var image = picture[randomNumber]

        imageView.image = image

        name = files[randomNumber]
        nameLabel.text = name

        }




}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: So, which error did you find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's problem in your image name .. Are you sure all images contain in you bundle file .. because you don't image in your file then it will return like this

**I Have tested this**

[image]

In this I have image **"no-photo-icon.png"** in my files but don't have **"pic/3.jpg"** . so its giving error like this .. 
Explain your error with full details .

Comment: Thanks for helping , the problem is solves .
it seems that the pic in the file couldn't been scan so i have put the pic into song files